# How to find fully qualified references in JDT ICompilationUnit or IType

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm looking for a way to find all types that are used in a fully qualified way in a JDT ICompilationUnit.

My goal is to find a list of all "referenced" packages in a project. For all things that are imported, the code is pretty straight forward:

```
for (ICompilationUnit unit : units) {
    try {
        for (IImportDeclaration id : unit.getImports()) {
            String en = id.getElementName();

            // strip off class name or .*
            target.add(en.substring(0, en.lastIndexOf('.')));
        }
    } catch (JavaModelException me) {
        // ...
    }

    // TODO: find fully qualified references from source code?
}
```

The TODO is the thing I'm interested in :) Best would be a way that does NOT involve full compiler roundtrips or other huge performance hits - but I'll accept them if not otherwise possible...